# Putting a comma between tags of the scss

Tags: javascript, css, sass

So I have the following code in the head file:

```
<div class='topic-poster'>
  <a href="/u/${username}" data-user-card="${username}">
    <img alt="" width="50" height="50" src="${avatar}" class="avatar">
  </a>
</div>

....

<div class="topic-statuses">
    <a href="/t/${slug}/${id}" class="title raw-link raw-topic-link">${title}</a>
    <div class="topic-post-tags">${tags}</div>
</div>
```

In the scss file:

```
.topic-statuses{
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

And the output is:

[image]

first and second are tags (`${tag}`).
How do I add an comma or '|' between first and second?

Comment: What is first and what is second?

Comment: @connexo they are just tags that `${tags}` takes.

Answer (score 0):

try to insert another div container between the 2 elements with the character , in it.

```
 <div class='topic-poster'>
     <a href="/u/${username}" data-user-card="${username}">
       <img alt="" width="50" height="50" src="${avatar}" class="avatar">
     </a>
 </div>

<div> , </div>

<div class="topic-statuses">
    <a href="/t/${slug}/${id}" class="title raw-link raw-topic-link">${title}</a>
    <div class="topic-post-tags">${tags}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: they are not in the same place through, it won't solve it.

Comment: hmm, then you will have to build the tags string with the commas between elements built in.

Comment: instead of tags being tags='firstseondthirdfourth', construct it like this: tags='first,seond,third,fourth'